# How to share file with room in HipChat via Postman or Jersey client?

Tags: rest, jersey, postman, hipchat

Please provide the solution for this (I am new to jersey and postman). I tried with below link but unable to share the file: https://www.hipchat.com/docs/apiv2/method/share_file_with_room

I attached screen shots, which I tried from postman.

[image]

[image]

Note:  I used API access token with send message scope.

I am getting below error as response:

```
{
"error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "No file was found in the request. See https://www.hipchat.com/docs/apiv2/method/share_file_with_room for an example",
"type": "Bad Request"
}
}
```

Comment: Would you show readers what you have so far?